# How do I convert a long to a string in C++?

Tags: c++

How do I convert a `long` to a `string` in C++?

Comment: Just a bit of nitpicking... I wouldn't call this "casting".

Comment: @krbyrd could you tell me why? I`m a .NETist myself, c++ still feels uncomfortable for me. :)

Comment: Agree, this is a conversion and not a cast.

Comment: Ah... got the point. My mistake.

Comment: I find the word "casting" is overloaded in general. People use it anywhere where they want to say "converting". Such things as "implicit casts" do not exist: an cast is always explicit. This is a sort of programmer-ignorance pet-peeve to me :)

Comment: use ltoa, its in the standard lib http://www.cs.usyd.edu.au/~kev/pp/RESOURCES/cplusplus/ref/cstdlib/ltoa.html

Comment: Somehow that ltoa didn't work for me. Feeling quite dumb when trying to accomplish something in c++. For me it's even worse than javascript. :)

Comment: @litb There is one more thing - english is not my native language. I'm confusing precise meaning of similar words quite often.

Comment: btw, I do love javascript now. strange how things are changin :)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You could use stringstream.

```
#include <sstream>

// ...
std::string number;
std::stringstream strstream;
strstream << 1L;
strstream >> number;
```

There is usually some proprietary C functions in the standard library for your compiler that does it too. I prefer the more "portable" variants though.

The C way to do it would be with sprintf, but that is not very secure. In some libraries there is new versions like sprintf_s which protects against buffer overruns.

Answer (score 101):

In C++11, there are actually [std::to_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) and [std::to_wstring](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_wstring) functions in <string>.

```
string to_string(int val);
string to_string(long val);
string to_string(long long val);
string to_string(unsigned val);
string to_string(unsigned long val);
string to_string(unsigned long long val);
string to_string(float val);
string to_string(double val);
string to_string (long double val);
```

Answer (score 29):

Well if you are fan of copy-paste, here it is:

```
#include <sstream>

template <class T>
inline std::string to_string (const T& t)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << t;
    return ss.str();
}
```

Comment: You missed `template <typename T>`.

Comment: Well it can be discussed,it is up to compiler implementation, templates are only expanded inline when the compiler deems it appropriate

Comment: The same holds for inline functions. Surprisingly, the `inline` keyword has little to do with code inlining (at least since 1998, anyway) --- it merely marks a function so that the linker doesn't complain about multiple definitions.

Answer (score 20):

`boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(my_long)`
more here http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm

Comment: +1, although originally, lexical_cast did little more than the accepted stringstream example (just wrapped up more expressively).

Answer (score 20):

You can use [**std::to_string**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) in C++11

```
long val = 12345;
std::string my_val = std::to_string(val);
```

Answer (score 13):

```
int main()
{
    long mylong = 123456789;
    string mystring;
    stringstream mystream;
    mystream << mylong;
    mystring = mystream.str();
    cout << mystring << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I don't know what kind of homework this is, but most probably the teacher doesn't want an answer where you just call a "magical" existing function (even though that's the recommended way to do it), but he wants to see if you can implement this by your own.

Back in the days, my teacher used to say something like "I want to see if you can program by yourself, not if you can find it in the system." Well, how wrong he was ;) ..

Anyway, if your teacher is the same, here is *the hard way* to do it..

```
std::string LongToString(long value)
{
  std::string output;
  std::string sign;

  if(value < 0)
  {
    sign + "-";
    value = -value;
  }

  while(output.empty() || (value > 0))
  {
    output.push_front(value % 10 + '0')
    value /= 10;
  }

  return sign + output;
}
```

You could argue that using `std::string` is not "the hard way", but I guess what counts in the actual agorithm.

Comment: This time it's fine to use ready functions. But thanks for this neat idea.

Comment: Really? He's just checking if you can _find_ a function somewhere? Yeah, times have changed ;) ..

Comment: @beef2k Even better - he notices that i know OOP, feels impressed and doesn't check anything else. :)

Comment: @Blindy here are some semi-random links in case you want to get a bit clearer picture of what I know - http://pastebin.com/k4YAqUXy

Comment: Would it *not* be faster as compared to other solutions using `std::stringstream` ?

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways.  Read [The String Formatters of Manor Farm](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill19.htm) for an in-depth comparison.

Comment: Yes.  This is at least the third time I've linked it on SO.  8v)

Answer (score 4):

```
   #include <sstream>


   ....

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << a_long_int;  // or any other type
    std::string result=ss.str();   // use .str() to get a string back
```

Comment: It's std::string, not std::String.

Answer (score 2):

Check out `std::stringstream`.

Answer (score 2):

One of the things not covered by anybody so far, to help you think about the problem further, is what format should a long take when it is cast to a string.

Just have a look at a spreedsheet program (like Calc/Excel).  Do you want it rounded to the nearest million, with brackets if it's negative, always to show the sign.... Is the number realy a representation of something else, should you show it in Oractal or Hex instead?

The answers so far have given you some default output, but perhaps not the right ones.

Comment: Love it, I give a considered answer to the question to help with the thinking about the homework rather than giving the answer that was already there and I get a downvote, meanwhile 'std::stringstream' has an upvote...

Answer (score -1):

The way I typically do it is with sprintf. So for a long you could do the following assuming that you are on a 32 bit architecture:

```
char buf[5] = {0}; // one extra byte for null    
sprintf(buf, "%l", var_for_long);
```

Comment: -1. While a C++ compiler will compile your code, it should certainly not be called C++. Additionally, I doubt 5 characters is enough.

Comment: Please don't advocate sprintf in this day and age. Don't we have enough buffer overrun exploits? Not that this code seems to have any as written - but you never know how things change.

Comment: Phil, the buffer will overflow for any number above 10000.

Comment: avakar - you're absolutely right :-s that'll teach me to post to SO on the way home from the pub.

Comment: I agree that there are some dangers with the printf family but I don't think that we can run away from them. In a perfect world we could ignore them but I work in a c++ code base that uses them and it's good to know how / why they are dangerous. Anytime you approach low level system programming you will run into these calls. Admittedly my example wasn't the best but now it's documented why it was bad and others can learn from it. Internally we use asprintf and vasprintf to safeguard against buffer overruns.