# Convert a Long in a String C++?

Tags: c++, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ long to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947621/c-long-to-string)
>   [Easiest way to convert int to string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c)

I am use to Java where I could just use `.toString()` on almost anything but I am trying a few problems in C++

I can not figure out how to make a `long` value into a `string`.

Answer (score 9):

You can either use a string stream:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

long x;
// ...
std::ostringstream ss;
ss << x;

std::string result = ss.str();
```

Or you can use Boost's `lexical_cast`:

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
std::string s = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(x);
```

I think it's a [common opinion](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill19.htm) that this aspect of the language isn't quite as elegant as it could be.

In the new C++11, things are a bit easier, and you can use the `std::to_string()` function:

```
#include <string>
std::string s = std::to_string(x);
```

Comment: Added another standard solution for completeness :) Also, I noted that inline editing silently steps over other people's changes.

Comment: @RMF: Thanks for the edit, I didn't know that! Maybe the days of inelegance are over!

Comment: @Seth: Yes, that did not exist in the previous versions of the standard. Also the inverse operations like `stoi()` and `strtoull()` have overloads for `std::string` in C++11.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::ostringstream ss;
long i = 10;
ss << i;
std::string str = ss.str();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a stringstream.

```
std::ostringstream ss;
ss << aLongNumber;
ss.str()
```

You use operator `<<` like `iostream` `cout` and `cin`. And you use `str()` method to get the string.