# How to convert DWORD to char *?

Tags: c++

I am trying something like this,

```
PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo = .....
strcat( args, processInfo.dwProcessId);
```

where `args` is a `char *` which I need to pass as an argument to another executable.

Comment: A `DWORD` is an integer type. It doesn't make any sense to convert it to a `char*`.

Comment: But I need this `DWORD` to be passed as an argument to another exe called using CreateProcess(). Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ long to string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947621/c-long-to-string) or [How to convert an int to string in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257714/how-to-convert-an-int-to-string-in-c).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use sprintf

```
char procID[10];
sprintf(procID, "%d", processInfo.dwProcessId);
```

This will convert the processInfo.dwProcessId into a character which can then be used by you.

Comment: Among all possible options, I think this is the optimized one.

Comment: Should probably use `%u` as `DWORD` is an unsigned integer.

Comment: Actually, `DWORD` is an `unsigned long`, and you should use `%lu` as the format specifier.

Answer (score 3):

To convert DWORD to char * you can use _ultoa / _ultoa_s

see here might help you.[link1](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-391225.html)

Answer (score 2):

MSDN has pretty good documentation, check out the [Data Conversion page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0heszx3w.aspx).

There's [sprintf()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybk95axf.aspx) too.

Answer (score 1):

While not directly "converting to a `char*`", the following should do the trick:

```
std::ostringstream stream;
stream << processInfo.dwProcessId;
std::string args = stream.str();

// Then, if you need a 'const char*' to pass to another Win32
// API call, you can access the data using:
const char * foo = args.c_str();
```